# When to choose which type of Delphi unit?

Tags: delphi

This may be a simple, stupid question, but I am trying to create a unit that will be a .dcu compiled unit for use with other units. Do I choose to create a program, unit or library?

There will be no graphics, just commands and functions.

Which do I choose? A program, unit or library?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a unit, then create a unit.

If you need a DLL/BPL, then create a library/package.

If you need an EXE, create a program.

Comment: Extension wise: if you want a DCU, create a unit. Bonus: the L in both DLL/BPL stands for **l**ibrary. It can't be much simpler to distinguish...

Comment: I figured it was a stupid question, but the unit I have created is acting weird, so I need to start over.